# ruby on rail deployment issue- You have already activated rack 1.5.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.4.4. Using bundle exec may solve this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thin

I try to deploy ruby on rails application with thin. I got this error

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup': You have already activated rack 1.5.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.4.4. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /var/www/rails/mgm/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /var/www/rails/mgm/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /var/www/rails/mgm/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /var/www/rails/mgm/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.5.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rack-1.5.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /var/www/rails/mgm/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from /var/www/rails/mgm/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:42:in `for'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:169:in `load_adapter'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:73:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.5.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/thin:19:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I added to Gemfile

```
 gem 'rack' '1.5.1'
```

and ran

```
bundle update rack
```

I got following error

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.2.8) ruby depends on
      rack (~> 1.4.0) ruby

    rack (1.5.1)
```

I ran

```
 bundle exec
```

return

```
bundler: exec needs a command to run
```

Comment: Which version of Rack lies in here : **/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/** (or in the Gemfile of your application if you created one, which you should have done) ? rack 1.5.1 may be installed but your Gemfile requires the 1.4.4... Have you tried changing the statement in your Gemfile from 1.4.4 to 1.5.1 ?

Comment: @Sparda update at main thead

Comment: did you try running it with `bundle exec`?

Comment: @icn ok so your Rails version depends  on rack 1.4.4 so replace 1.5.1 with `~> 1.4.0` like it was before and try to update your gems like you did. If it doesn't work, try to uninstall rack with `gem uninstall rack` and run bundle install again.

Comment: @Sparda thanks a lot:) "gem uninstall rack" has the issue resolved

Comment: Ok, I'm posting the answer so that others who find your question get the point right away ; )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to uninstall rack with

```
gem uninstall rack
```

and run

```
bundle install
```

Comment: This is all fine and good if you only work in 1 environment and only require 1 version of rack to be installed, but `bundle exec` (as the error message suggests) is there exactly for this situation.  One should really use `bundle exec` or if that's undesirable/insufficient, some other kind of gem set management (e.g. rvm gemsets) to make sure the project is loading the same gems wherever it's run (e.g. dev vs prod).

Comment: Managing gems through gemsets is what I recommended in my first comment on icn's question ; )

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command to:

```
bundle update
```